# Set custom weight of simple product in Magento based on value of selected custom option

Tags: magento

I have a Magento site for a company that sells custom signs. I have custom options set up so that the customer can choose the material and size that they need. My problem is that I need to be able to dynamically calculate the weight of the sign based on the material and the size selected. I have calculated the weight with javascript and now I'm trying to pass it through to Magento using the checkout_product_add_after event.

I've set up a custom option titled Weight that is a text input field. I hide the input field with javascript and pass in the calculated weight. I can access the weight with my custom module and set the weight using the setWeight() method, but when I go through to the checkout, the weight has not been updated and the shipping rates haven't changed. I've tried setting the weight on both the quote item and the product and neither work.

Here is the code from my Observer.php file:

```
<?php

class XM_CustomWeight_Model_Observer {

  public function set_custom_weight($observer) {

    $event = $observer->getEvent();
$product = $event->getProduct();
$options = $product->getCustomOptions();
    $last = end($options);
    $weight = $last->getValue();
$product->setWeight($weight);
$product->save();

  }
}
```

Has anyone ever run into this problem and found a good solution? Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look @ [Magento - Programmatically saved product not visible in backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335279/magento-programmatically-saved-product-not-visible-in-backend)

I think you may need to set the store id as Admin

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage::getModel('core/store')->load(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID));
```

Have you think about the possibility of **multiple customers buying the same item** within few seconds of each, the first person may/will get the the weight amount of the last person or if a customer changes zipcode during checkout and need to recalculate shipping.

What I think you could do is create a custom shipping module (by extending the current one), then add a custom weight to each line item, and use this custom_weight to help calculate shipping cost

Take a look @ [How to add custom fields for Order Line Items in magento](http://mayankzalavadia.wordpress.com/2012/07/21/how-to-add-custom-fields-for-order-line-items-in-magento/)

Comment: Setting the store id as Admin did indeed work! I did not think of the issue you have presented though. Will I run into this same problem if I set the weight of the quote item rather than the product? Using the posted solution of adding custom fields for Order Line items, I'm assuming I'll need to set the weight of the quote item rather than the product, correct? Thanks for your help!

Comment: A quote is per order and not global to everyone like product, so you should not have this issue